# NSDocument data:ofType implementation when using NSPrintInfo (storing multiple items)

Tags: swift

I'm a newbie to Swift (5) and Cocoa development trying to develop a NSDocument based application. In my document (subclassed from NSDocument) I have a few properties, an enum, an int and an array of objects. The objects implement the NSCoding protocol. The application also implements printing and so I would like to save/load the NSPrintInfo property (printInfo on the NSDocument base class).

My question is how should I implement my data:ofType function override to accompish saving:

- printInfo from NSDocument
- My local int and enum
- My local array of NSCoding implementing objects

In the examples I’ve seen, NSKeyedArchiver is used but this just creates a single NSData object from a given single root object, whereas I have multiple objects to store. I could create a new data object to hold all the properties I wish to store, but then how should I refer back to the printInfo property on NSDocument?

Answer (score 0):

Just for information for anyone who reads this; I did solve this issue by:
 - Creating a custom class to hold my data and an `NSPrintInfo` copy of the NSDocument `printInfo` member
 - Overriding the `printInfo` variable on my NSDocument class to add a didSet which copies the NSDocument `printInfo` to my copy on my custom data object

```
class MyDocument: NSDocument, NSKeyedUnarchiverDelegate
{
    /// The printing information associated with the document.
    override var printInfo: NSPrintInfo
    {
        didSet
        {
            // Update the data object used to save data
            myData.printInfo = printInfo
        }
    }
}
```

- Copying the loaded custom data `printInfo` back to the NSDocument on reading saved data

  override func read( from data: Data, ofType typeName: String ) throws
  {

  ```
  let loaded = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData( data )
  if let loadedData = loaded as? MyData
  {
      // Update the data object from the loaded data
      myData = loadedData

      // Now update the local printInfo
      undoManager?.disableUndoRegistration()
      printInfo = myData.printInfo
      undoManager?.enableUndoRegistration()
  }
  else
  {
      throw MyError.BadData
  }
  ```

  }
- Note: The disabling of the undo manager before setting the `printInfo` prevents this code from marking the document as stale and therefore in need of saving